# Cowboy framework: Sending HTTP calls

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I want to send an HTTP request within Cowboy framework, and read the response’s body. Is there any meta level functionality to do so or I should go down to Erlang to do it? From the document I only see ‘handlers’. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Cowboy` is an HTTP server, for sending HTTP request you require some HTTP client such as `hackney` https://github.com/benoitc/hackney.

Answer (score 1):

The [cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy) is a Erlang server application but for sending HTTP request you can use libraries like [gun](https://github.com/ninenines/gun), [shot](https://github.com/e4q/shot) or you can use [httpc](https://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) directly out of the box of Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

Cowboy is a web server, it is not a framework. It does not provide HTTP client functionality of sending requests and receiving responses. Its role is opposite, it supports receiving requests from clients and responding to them.

In order to send requests you need HTTP client. In Erlang you can choose among several. [httpc](https://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) is part of Erlang distribution. The team which developed Cowboy also created [Gun](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/gun/2.0/guide/introduction/), an asynchronous HTTP client. There exist several others.

Comment: Why cowboy cannot be classified as a web framework?

Comment: @Viacheslav Cowboy is direct equivalent of packages like Apache or nginx. They are normally described as web servers not web frameworks. Frameworks normally support functionalities like templating, session management, database access, etc. I think addressing Cowboy as web framework would be misleading, and Cowboy authors say "cowboy - Small, fast, modern HTTP server for Erlang/OTP".

Comment: I see. Got it. Looks like the tag `web-framework` in cowboy github page misled me. As I understand then cowboy can be classified as web server erlang library or application, because templating can be done by erlydtl and database access byt other similar librairies and applications like epgsql, eredis etc. Then when we collect cowboy/gun/epgsql/eredis then we can say that this is a web-framework - correct?

Comment: @Viacheslav Correct!